.command file osascript opening Terminal: when closed, results in "Do you want to terminate ..." dialog; how to avoid
On your Mac simply open Terminal, or if open, just tap command-N
You now have a new Terminal window.
Simply close it, command-W or tap the red dot.
That Terminal window / that shell just closes.
Next have a .command file
 osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set bounds of first window to {1100, 50, 1100 + 500, 50 + 250}"
 cd ~/Desktop

Note 1, due to THIS factoid https://superuser.com/a/207763/401734 an oddity in how Terminal handles incoming "do script" commands; it creates a new window for each one that's seemingly how you "open a new Terminal window" when using a .command file
But that leaves the open window in a useless state, "[Process completed]" it indeed opens the window but closes the shell. so - as far as I know - the best bet is this:
 osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set bounds of first window to {1100, 50, 1100 + 500, 50 + 250}"
 cd ~/Desktop
 $SHELL

Or just use 'zsh' as the last line as preferred
This all works great so far, you can launch a new Terminal window, set the size, color etc and execute any initial commands.
However!  Now simply close that new window,
disaster! you get

which is very inconvenient.
the problem could be that the shell launched by the osascript is owned by someone unusual, not whoever owns the shell when Terminal itself opens a new window?  Or perhaps the permissions are wrong or ?
Is there any solution to this issue?

Solved by @nohillside !
Essentially just set ...

for the relevant profiles.
(Indeed you can do this if preferred for the default window, unrelated to using osascript/.command files.)
